# Sugestions for textfield

Tags: automation, textfield

i have a question about a suggestion possibility in textfields.

What i am looking for is a script that gives user suggestions for the text they type.
It is used for a song request page of a radio station, and what i am looking for is a script that provides suggestions for the artists, and after filling the artist form, automatically suggest songs by the requested artist.

We like to create a more easy request form for our listeners, so they first type the artist, and offcourse the artists shown are available in our database, and than when they complete the artist field, automatically the system knows the songs available for that artist, and give the suggestions for the song.

I hope this is understandable and i hope you can give me suggestions about this.

Thank you for your help and looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "page" I assume you are talking about a web page. A standard way to do this then would be the JQuery [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) UI widget.

Comment: Indeed i did mean webpage. Thank you for the suggestion, i will try it at once, Thank you very much